Is the idea that "All mathematical truth are truths relative to the FAS that they are expressed in" flawed?
I am a Math graduate and throughout my career as a computer programmer I have maintained a deep interest in mathematics among other topics.  While I have never read it stated directly I have had for a while come to the understanding that truth in mathematics is relative to the context of the Formal Axiomatic System(FAS) that it is expressed in.
Now obviously there are systems of math that predate the development of the concepts of FAS or even logic but these are sort of operating in a naïve FAS that the users are unaware of.
Have I come to a understanding that is fundamentally flawed?  Alternatively if this way of thinking of mathematics corresponds to a specific philosophy of mathematics please tell me the name that this is given and what literature I can seek to get a deeper understanding.

You might be interested in a very old mathematics book, maybe the first mathematics book: Euclid's Elements. It is written with an axiomatic structure. It led to almost two and a half millennia (so far) of the further development of axiomatic mathematics (in addition to developments of geometry, number theory, etc.).

I have a copy of Euclid's elements.  However Euclid thought that his assumptions where the only ones possible.  It took until Gauss and Taurinus to show that noneuclidian geo was possible.

Besides the issue of what Euclid thought (who knew what he thought?), what you are saying is pretty much what I am saying: Euclid's axiomatic method, and the mathematical problems that arose from his mathematical work, became the model for mathematics for thousands of years. But I am trying to make one more point: almost nothing in the written history of mathematics "predates" the axiomatic method, because Euclid was already using it, however imperfectly. So, far from being flawed, the axiomatic method has been around for a long time, and is still being used.

Your understanding agrees with mine: mathematical truth is only relative to the FAS it is derived in. You may find it helpful to read about formalism https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formalism_(philosophy_of_mathematics) which takes this perspective to the extreme, or to ask on the philosophy stackexchange.
